# Defining tasks in a Docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized an older system that I work on. I have a docker compose file referencing an image built on postgres and an image built on tomcat.  This compose file is working well for starting and stopping a test version of the application.

#### Compose file

```
services:
  db:
    image: mypostgres
    container_name: db
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  tomcat:
    image: mytomcat
    container_name: tomcat
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - myhost=localhost
    volumes:
      - "mydata:/mydata"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

#### Running tasks within one of the containers

I have some additional command line tasks that I would like to perform on the system.  Some of these tasks are compute intensive.  These tasks operate on files in the mydata volume.

Currently, I use the following command to run this task within the tomcat container.

```
docker exec tomcat /bin/my-script.sh param
```

#### Could these tasks be defined with docker-compose?

I think that it could make sense to create a separate container to run this task.  If I was to define this as a service, it would look like the following.

```
  mycli:
    image: mytomcat
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - myhost=tomcat
    volumes:
      - "mydata:/mydata"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mycli
    entrypoint: /bin/myscript.sh
    command:
      - param
```

What would the best practice for such a configuration?

#### What seems good about adding this to the compose file

- The long-running task runs in a separate container.
- The availability of the task is nicely defined.
- This could be a nice way to perform a data initialization task.

#### What seems bad about adding this to the compose file

- Some action must take place when the service is started.  Once that action is completed, the container is in an exited status.
- If I run a task with `docker-compose run`, the exited tasks seem to be hanging around after execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could these tasks be defined with docker-compose?

No; the `docker-compose.yml` file only defines long-running "service" containers.  There's no way to define an additional `docker exec` type task that you'd run on an already-started container.  You could in principle define additional "services" that do their unit of work and exit immediately, but every time you ran `docker-compose up` it would want to re-run all of them.

> a data initialization task

If you have something that needs to run at first startup (like preloading data) or every startup (maybe database migrations) you can structure your container so that it runs before the main application starts.  I tend to do this sort of thing in an entrypoint script; it takes the container's command as command-line arguments, so it has a chance to make a decision based on which command is being run, do the required setup, and then actually launch the command.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "theapp" ]; then
  # Hypothetically: if we're starting theapp, run its migrations
  # first before running the service itself
  theapp migrate
fi
# Now do whatever the command is
exec "$@"
```

A particularly involved example of this pattern is the [mysql image's entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/696fc899126ae00771b5d87bdadae836e704ae7d/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh): if it's launching the database, and the data directory doesn't already exist, then it does all of the first-time setup, launching a temporary database server while it does this.

> additional [...] tasks that I would like to perform

You might see whether you can add network calls that trigger them, either on a protected "admin" URL path or on a separate port that's not published externally.  That would avoid the problem of needing to get a root shell to do routine maintenance tasks.

Failing that, a shell script to automate the task and its arguments will at least save you some typing and memorization.